# Linq.Orderby for timezone times using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting different timezone time in a List. I want to order them by minus --> plus (ascending). For example, I have given some of the country time.

**+5:45
-8:00
0:00
-5:00
-7.30
+5:30**

I want this list to be sorted in this order.

**-8:00
-7:00
-5:00
0:00
+5:30
+5:45**

How do I do that using LINQ OrderBy?

The main point is, it should be sorted first by the sign and not by the number.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: How your code does with `OrderBy`? What problem you got?

Comment: I am getting values like the below

Comment: What data type do you have? `string`, `List<string>`, `List<DateTimeOffset>` etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "timezone times" in the list are stored as strings, you could order the list using OrderBy as follows (edited):

```
OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Replace(':', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Note that double.Parse("+1.234") still works, that is, you don't have to remove the '+' sign in front of every string with a '+' sign in front.

Comment: That would only work if the locale of the PC is one that has a dot as decimal sign.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That can be solved by using the overload of Parse that uses a IFormatProvider `OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Replace(':', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Indeed. My comment was meant to make the author to include that. Unfortunately, that didn't work and I forgot about it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Indeed, my comment was meant to show the OP any any other reader the solution to the problem you presented due to the OP not updating his answer :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure how to get notifications on comments, so I didn't really check back here! On that note, edited :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TimeSpan` type:

```
.OrderBy(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.TrimStart('+')))
```

Note that while `Parse` allows negative values, any leading `+` must be trimmed.